# iphone NSMutableUrlRequest Compression

Tags: iphone, nsmutableurlrequest

I have set my compression like this for my **NSMutableUrlRequest** on my iphone app (I use Monotouch, but it's a 1:1 API match):

```
var req = new NSMutableUrlRequest (new NSUrl (str), NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, 20)
req["Accept-Encoding"] = "compress, gzip";
```

When I download a resource (REST xml file) and monitor the bandwidth in the iPhoneSimulator, it indicates that the file is being downloaded at its raw file size (20 meg, zipped should be 3 meg-ish).

On my IIS 6 server I have set compression universally. Using a browser to the file works fine with compression when I monitor its bandwidth usage.

Ideas why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to configure IIS to compress XML files as well. More information at http://www.modernsignal.com/settingupgzipcompressioniniis

Answer (score 1):

```
[req addValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accepts-Encoding"];
```

Maybe your solution would work like this **"Accepts-Encoding"**

```
req["Accepts-Encoding"] = "compress, gzip";
```

Additional discussion [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-download-and-process-gzipd-data.html)

Comment: That one should be "Accept-Encoding". http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html